# WordPress 3 on MAMP OS X

Tags: macos, wordpress, wordpress-theming, mamp

I am using WordPress 3 on MAMP OS X.

1) Under my installation of MAMP, under the htdocs directory, I have a WordPress site installation, say called Site A.

I now want to create a new WordPress site, for Site B, do I need to download a new install of WordPress and then set this up under htdocs, now called Site B and new Site B database - is this the correct procedure?

2) I understand that WordPress needs a styles.css file under CSS, the site I want to move into WordPress has a styles.css plus 3 other CSS files that it needs.

What is the best practice with incorporating the other 3 stylesheet files, so that they are used as part of WordPress, i.e do I need to call them from within styles.css?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress 3.0 [supports multiple sites out of the box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) (it used to be a separate codebase, [WordPress MultiUser](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU)). So yes, you can use the same install, but if you prefer to keep it simple you can just install two WordPress installations side-by-side.

If you want to [create your own theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), you do need at least a `style.css` file with some information about the theme in a comment block. WordPress will read this info and display it in the admin area. But a theme can also contain other files (should, in fact), like a `header.php` and a `footer.php`. In the `header.php`, you probably put the code to load your stylesheet. This can be `style.css`, but it doesn't have to be. You can include any stylesheet(s) you want, including the three files you have now (just write multiple `<link rel="stylesheet">` tags). But including them via `@include` in `style.css` is fine too: the choice is up to you.